# Locate where the exception is thrown in a 'try catch' block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'll explain by example:

```
        try
        {
            func1();

            func2();

            func3();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"func{i} thrown an exception");
        }
```

I want to be able have 'i' hold the function number that thrown the exception (if func2() caused the exception, it should be 2).
What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the content of `ex.StackTrace`. Or declare a variable before the `try` and set it `i = 1; func1(); i = 2; func2(); i = 3; func3();`

Comment: or use a separate try-block for each function

Comment: The location of the exception, most specifically the line number, file, and method are located in the StackStrace of the message, to access it use `ex.StrackTrace`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I'd do that only if you still want to try to execute every function if the first or second throws an exception

Comment: The `ex` variable itself references the `Exception` object, which has a `StackTrace` property that tells you exactly where the exception was thrown. It's a `string` value. If you need a finer-grained representation, you can create a new `StackTrace` object from the `ex` value and examine that. See duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ex.Messsage property.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            func1();
            func2();
            func3();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"func[{ex.Message}] thrown an exception");
        }
    }

    private static void func3()
    {
        throw new Exception("3");
    }

    private static void func2()
    {
        throw new Exception("2");
    }

    private static void func1()
    {
        throw new Exception("1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomeErrorHandler(() => {
  CustomeErrorHandler(() => func1(), "func1 thrown an exception", reThrowError = true);
  CustomeErrorHandler(() => func2(), "func2 thrown an exception", reThrowError = true);
  CustomeErrorHandler(() => func3(), "func3 thrown an exception", reThrowError = true);
})


public static void CustomeErrorHandler(Action a, string error = string.Empty, bool reThrowError = false) 
{
  try {
   a();
  }
  catch{
   if(!reThrowError) Console.WriteLine(error);
   if(reThrowError) throw new Exception(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the exception details in ex.stackTrace.